# SP 2010: Excel Calculation Services is not restarting

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, excel, excel-services, excel-access-web-part

Excel Calculation Services is not restarting, and when researched, i found an error

**There was an error in communicating with Excel Calculation Services http://server:32843/2695bd8db6fc474fa8yhatthutrgg/ExcelService*.asmx exception: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. [Session: User: xyz/abc].**

and when looked for 2695bd8db6fc474fa8yhatthutrgg **application** in IIS application pool, i didn't find any application..!!

users are not able to open excel sheets in browser, please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the points to troubleshoot your issue:

In the IIS, right click the application pools->View applications->check if there is excel serive in it. If so, make sure the application pool is running.

Go to SharePoint central administration->manage services on servers->check if the "excel calculation service" is started, if so, stop and restart it.

clear SharePoint configuration cache and run IIS reset and check again.

Beside, here is a similar post for your reference: [Excel Services Application issues (SP 2010/2013)](https://collab365.community/excel-services-application-issues-sp-2010-2013/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried that... i got below error.

Error 
An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object ExcelServerWebServiceInstance was updated by domain/user, in the w3wp (3788) process, on machine SERVER.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: XX-XXX-XXX-XXX

Date and Time: 3/6/2020 8:29:19 AM 

Go back to site Go back to site